# Schedule UILocalNotificatiions on Every Day or on specific Days of the week?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I am working on an Alarm project which needs to set Local Notifications but the problem is that i need to repeat them on Every sunday or every monday or might be on both of sunday or monday ,
 can Any one help me how to solve it,?
 Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3) has a property called `repeatInterval`.

However, it only specifies the interval at which you want the notification to repeat, depending on the `fireDate` that your user specified.

Say, the fire date was on a monday; if the repeat interval was set like so,

```
yourLocalNotif.repeatInterval =  kCFCalendarUnitWeekday;
```

the notification would go off every single monday.

Now, if you want to have repeating notifications for a monday and a sunday both, you would have to create 2 different Local Notification objects, one with a fireDate set for monday and another set for sunday, and both with the `repeatInterval` property set for `kCFCalendarUnitWeekday`.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing that it is the repeating that is the problem. take a look at [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/51117-uilocalnotification-question.html).
and i guess you know that u instantiate a UILocalNotification object and then you schedule it using the UIApplication method `scheduleLocalNotification:`. as you can read in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html), 4th text passage.